# Selenium JS how to get text of an element

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, async-await, css-selectors

I have searched for an answer, and this should be relatively easy but how do I go about grabbing the text from a populated table in a browser?

The "inspect" looks something like this:

```
<tr role="row">
  <th class="component-body-text" colspan="1"role="columnheader">### The Text I want ###</th>
```

Obviously there is more to the table than this, but I just want to be able to grab that piece of text?

would I do something like

```
await driver.findElement(By.className('component-body-text')).getText();
```

because that does not work. Or since there are multiple elements in the table should I

```
const sample = await driver.findElements(By.className('component-body-text')); 
sampleText = sample[0].getText();
```

I have tried both methods.

Comment: What do you mean by not work? Do you get an error message or the wrong value?

Comment: What does  "console.log(driver.findElement(By.className('component-body-text')))"  show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text **The Text I want** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *className*:

  ```
  await driver.findElement(By.className("component-body-text")).getText();
  ```
- Using *css*:

  ```
  await driver.findElement(By.css("tr[role='row'] > th.component-body-text[role='columnheader']")).getText();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@role='row']/th[@class='component-body-text' and @role='columnheader']")).getText();
  ```

Comment: className did not work for me. error message was "a device attached to the system is not functioning"

css worked as is. I mean, I fixed the parenthesis but other than that, excellent. thank you.

Comment: I see that someone downvoted. May I ask why? What I said in my comment was true. The suggestion worked out of the box for me. (again, className did not.)